# Laravel run Queue work from code

Tags: laravel, queue

I want to initiate queue:work from my code level rather than using any artisan commands or other supervisor, daemon listeners, so i don't have to do extra queue listeners stuff on background.

Is this possible or not ? If not how can i able to make process working on background when needed

Answer (score 4):

You can use following to call artisan command from the code.

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('queue:work', [
    '--option' => value,
]);
```

Note that if you call `queue:listener`, the code will enter into an infinite loop which would hang your existing process.

Comment: is it possible to run queue as background worker and process the remaining code

Comment: @PrajwolKC and others searching: [`queue:work --stop-when-empty`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#processing-all-queued-jobs-then-exiting)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the queue driver in the `config/queue.php` to `sync`. When you insert a job in the queue it will run immediately.

Comment: According to the docs, "A null queue driver is also included which simply discards queued jobs."